# Microsoft Graph Explorer Grant Permissions

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

I have few questions related to Microsoft Graph Explorer, any help is appreciated

1. If I am logging into Graph explorer portal (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to test the APIs, Let's say I use **name@XXXX.com** where **XXXX** is the tenant id, and the admin access is provided by the admin to **name@XXXX.com**, I am able to perform what I want. But if I login using **name@outlook.com**, how will my admin grant the admin access(which are required for few permissions), as **name@outlook.com** is not a tenant id or how will I get the admin permission to **name@outlook.com** ?
2. What exactly are **Delegated and Application** permissions in App Registration Portal.As I see in the Microsoft document it says, Delegated permissions are for **signed in users** present. Present as in , where exactly ? Is it like they belong to that particular tenant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how will my admin grant the admin access(which are required for few
>   permissions), as name@outlook.com is not a tenant id or how will I get
>   the admin permission to name@outlook.com ?

For this, you could assign the related directory role to name@outlook.com in the Azure portal.

[image]

> What exactly are Delegated and Application permissions in App
>   Registration Portal.As I see in the Microsoft document it says,
>   Delegated permissions are for signed in users present. Present as in ,
>   where exactly ? Is it like they belong to that particular tenant ?

**Delegated permissions**: Your client application needs to access the Web API as the signed-in user, but with access limited by the selected permission. This type of permission can be granted by a user unless the permission is configured as requiring administrator consent. And when your application makes calls by passing your client id, secret (if applicable) and the user's authentication token, your application's effective permissions will be the lowest combination of the user and your application.

**Application Permissions**: Your client application needs to access the Web API directly as itself (no user context). This type of permission requires administrator consent and is also not available for Native client applications.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sunny :) By the way, Where exactly do we need to register the app for using Microsoft Graph Explorer ? Document says under **App Registration Portal** but I see many people doing it in the Azure Portal under **AAD -> Add new application**

Comment: There is a difference to create an app between using Microsoft Graph Explorer and using the Azure portal. Microsoft Graph Explorer uses the v2 endpoint, you create an app can be seen in the  Application Registration Portal, but cannot be seen in the AAD; In the Azure portal, the v1 endpoint is used, the app you created can be seen in both the Azure Portal and  the Applicaiton Registration Portal.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation